# Why is a stage in my gitlab pipeline omitted?

Tags: gitlab

I have the following gitlab configuration:

```
stages:
  - test
  - stage1
  - stage2

test:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'echo "Running Test"'

my_stage1:
  stage: stage1
  script:
    - 'echo "Running stage 1"'

my_stage2:
  stage: stage2
  script:
    - 'echo "Running stage 2"'
```

and I create a merge request. I expect that *all three* stages are run in that case, but the first stage is *not* run. Why? How to fix it? The documentation on that it very unclear!

The content of `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is `merge-request-event`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules-clauses), when you are using a `when:never` it needs to be followed by a specific success clause, in order for it to run in other cases e.g.:

```
test:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
    - when: on_success
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I cannot see it in the documentation. What phrase exactly documents this?

Comment: Also, the first stage seem to run twice. Is that a bug in gitlab?

Comment: If you look for "In all other cases, the job is added to the pipeline, with when: on_success" you should find it. Not sure why it is now running twice though. I must admit that I find GitlabCI to be a bit of a dark art.